# How Can I indent only first line of multiline UILabel in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilabel

I want to add an image in start of UILabel. Label is multiline. If I use contentInset, it indent the whole label but I want to indent first line only.

I have tried this so far, this doesn't work for me.

```
    UIEdgeInsets titleInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    valueLabel.contentInset = titleInsets;
```

It should look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@DavidCaunt suggestion worked for me. I am sharing code here.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.firstLineHeadIndent = 50;

[attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:style range:range];

[valueLabel setAttributedText:attributedText];
```

Comment: I know this is the right approach, but did you try it with custom fonts. For me it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

As a user716216 pointed, additionally - we can use a tab with defined indent value:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragraphStyle.headIndent = 50;

label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:
    @"\tHow can i add image like this in start of UILabel? Label is multiline.........."
    attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}];
```

Comment: I had to indent 2 rows in one UILabel so I used:     **paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 7; paragraphStyle.headIndent = 7;**

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this in Interface Builder:

[image: Demonstrates how to indent the first line of a label in Interface Builder]