# How to indent first line of Label in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, label

I simply need to achieve something like this:

[image]

using:

```
        ZStack {
            Image.book
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 12, height: 10)
            Text(verbatim: entry.verse)
                .font(.openSansRegular(withSize: 11))
        }
```

But have no idea how to achieve it.

Similar question but for UILabel was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430685/how-can-i-indent-only-first-line-of-multiline-uilabel-in-ios)

Comment: Does any of the unicode characters meet your needs? If it does just prefix it.